# Rewrite existing attribute value from Xml String?

Tags: xml, xmlwriter

Is it possible to rewrite an existing attribute from an XML String?

If I have:

```
$xml_str = "<Root>
    <NodeA attr1="value1"></NodeA>
</Root>";

//rewrite $xml_str
```

How can I find the `NodeA` and at the same time rewrite value1?

```
// finally save xml string into a physical path
file_put_contents($xml_save_path.DS.$xml_filename, $xml_str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML to parse XML in PHP.

Here's a simplified version that will get you the `value1` and replace with `value2` then echo the new XML.

```
$xml_str = "<Root>
    <NodeA attr1='value1'></NodeA>
</Root>";

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

$doc->NodeA['attr1'] = 'value2';

echo $doc->asXML();
```

Comment: How do you do this with an XSD instead of "<NodeA attr1='value1'></NodeA>" with "<cfdi:Root><cfdi:NodeName attr1='novalue'></cfdi:NodeName></cfdi:root>" ??

Comment: Have a look at the simplexml documentation. I am not sure if it can handle namespaces